# Should I visit patients/dead people if I can't withstand sickness/illness/dead?

Tags: death, sick

I know that our prophet insisted visiting the homes of sick/ill/dead people.

I can't withstand the psychological pressure of visiting patients and dead.

Should I visit patients/dead people if I can't withstand sickness/illness/dead?

Comment: It is not mandatory, but recommended. You will be rewarded for these good deeds, and if you don't do them it is not a sin.

Comment: that is a part of one's life. Happy things | Sad things. Both together. You should learn to do it slowly if possible. But, what if you're ill and all your relatives too are being like you, then no one will visit you when you're ill. So, help in need is help in deed. :) Soothing the ill when he needs is what important, you can do it thru phone if you like **in the beginning** :)

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (PBUH) insisted on visiting the sick, and told how much will visitors be rewarded, but that's still Sunnah, it's not mandatory and not doing it is not violation of the orders of Allah, despite that you'll lose great rewarding and pleasure.

Besides, we should remember that Allah said:

> لَا يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا ۚ لَهَا مَا كَسَبَتْ
>   وَعَلَيْهَا مَا اكْتَسَبَتْ ۗ رَبَّنَا لَا تُؤَاخِذْنَا إِن نَّسِينَا
>   أَوْ أَخْطَأْنَا ۚ رَبَّنَا وَلَا تَحْمِلْ عَلَيْنَا إِصْرًا كَمَا
>   حَمَلْتَهُ عَلَى الَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِنَا ۚ رَبَّنَا وَلَا تُحَمِّلْنَا
>   مَا لَا طَاقَةَ لَنَا بِهِ ۖ وَاعْفُ عَنَّا وَاغْفِرْ لَنَا
>   وَارْحَمْنَا ۚ أَنتَ مَوْلَانَا فَانصُرْنَا عَلَى الْقَوْمِ
>   الْكَافِرِينَ
>
> *Sahih International Translation*
>
> **Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity.**
>   It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it
>   will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. "Our Lord,
>   do not impose blame upon us if we have forgotten or erred. Our Lord,
>   and lay not upon us a burden like that which You laid upon those
>   before us. **Our Lord, and burden us not with that which we have no
>   ability to bear.** And pardon us; and forgive us; and have mercy upon
>   us. You are our protector, so give us victory over the disbelieving
>   people."
>
> [[Surat Al-Baqarah:286]](http://quran.com/2/286)

So if visiting the sick is something more than you can bear, or if it will harm you, then of course you don't have to do it.

And Allah knows best.